# Server side event fires ocassionally

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a drop down list of products, a grid view displaying ordered products and a button to add the selected product from the drop down list to the grid view.

When someone clicks the Add New Product button, my server side click handler only fires some times and doesn't fire other times. What could be the problem?

```
    private void AddNewProductToGridView()
    {
        if (lstProducts.SelectedIndex < 0) return;

        Response.Write("Selected Index: " + lstProducts.SelectedValue + 
            "<br />Selected Text: " + lstProducts.SelectedItem.Text + 
            "<br />Selected Value: " + lstProducts.SelectedValue);
    }

    protected void btnAddProduct_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddNewProductToGridView();
    }
```

**Update**
Ok, immediately after I posted the question, the button's server side click event started firing normally every time. :D

However, there is another problem. I also have a text box for quantity. I want that that button act as the default button of the page, i.e. when the user enters a quantity and presses the enter key, the same server side method `AddNewProductToGridView` must be called.

So, I set the `AutoPostBack` property of the textbox to `True` and added an event handler for the text changed event of the text box like so:

```
    protected void txtQuantity_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddNewProductToGridView();
    }
```

About this I am positive that this event handler does not fire except for the first time I start the application.

**A later update**

I think I found the solution to my problem and learnt something new.

The Text_Changed event of the TextBox server side control, as the name suggests, does not fire if the Text property of the TextBox has not changed since the last post back. It is therefore unreliable as a means of triggering a postback.

Comment: Post the aspx concerning the Button.

Comment: I can tell you for sure that the `TextChanged` event fires very reliably. How are you handling the event handler? You must have missed something there.

Comment: You are quite right that `TextChanged` only fires if the text has changed. It's worth noting that this is irrespective of if there's a postback (eg when a postback occurs, Asp.Net compares the current value to previous value and decides if the event should be raised).

Answer (score 1):

> I also have a text box for quantity. I want that that button act as the default button of the page

Just specify the default button for the `<form>` such that it is this button rather than the 'final' one that ultimately would submit the form (if there is one):

```
<form defaultbutton="btnAddProduct">
  ...
</form>
```

There's no discrimination here as to which `TextBox`, or other input, will cause a submit upon hitting enter, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to submit the textbox changes on Enter key, you can simply use `<form>`, and the button would be a submit button. By default it will submit when Enter is pressed.